# linux unix posix EPOCH time format

Tags: date

I have some audit logs with a date stamp of the format

1532400673.760:2358773

what are the numbers after `.` and after `:` represent?

using a website epoch converter `1532400673` converts to `GMT: Tuesday, July 24, 2018 2:51:13 AM`

if I do `date -d @1532400673` I get `Mon Jul 23 22:51:13 EDT 2018`

but trying to do `date -d @1532400673.760:2358773` is invalid format.

Comment: .### is probably milliseconds the other digit I don't know. GMT and EDT are to different time and they are not the same explaning why you have two different date.

Comment: which OS ? suse ? redhat ? which audit logs ?

Comment: `.760` is likely to be milliseconds. `:2358773` is likely not to be part of the timestamp. Without information as to what generates that _audit log_, it's hard to tell what it might be.

Answer (score 3):

If we dive the source code,

```
% rpm -qi audit | grep http
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
URL         : http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/
...
% git clone https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace.git
% cd audit-userspace/
```

And then make a guess that the epoch is a `%d` flag to `printf` followed by a colon (it might also be a `%ld` or `%u` or `%lu` depending on whether `long` or `unsigned` is for some reason involved):

```
% grep -ri '%d:' . | tail -1
./auparse/test/auparse_test.py:            print("    event time: %d.%d:%d, host=%s" % (event.sec, event.milli, event.serial, none_to_null(event.host)))
```

we find some test code that indicates the fields are second, millisecond, and some sort of event serial number. From additional digging it appears these values are grouped together as they all belong to a particular memory structure. Hopefully the docs will have more information about what that serial number is...

Comment: See the description of the `-a` option in  `ausearch` man page.

Comment: Usually in `dmesg` they are since boot time, no idea here.